# Kotlin's With, for ruby

Tags: ruby, kotlin

Is there any function or way to simulate this [with](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html) in ruby?

It helps you to organize the code that acts over the same object, something like:

```
with(callDao) {
            whenever(deleteAll()).thenComplete()
            whenever(insertAll(any())).thenComplete()
}
```

vs

```
            whenever(callDao.deleteAll()).thenComplete()
            whenever(callDao.insertAll(any())).thenComplete()
```

Comment: Noting that `with` can lead to confusing code, and difficult analysis; one reason it was deprecated in JS. I've never been a fan.

Comment: To stitch onto others, if you know a part of the code will always apply to a certain object, it is a very good argument for making that code into a method on that object.

Comment: I second @Amadan's concept however I have leveraged such techniques as module methods in the past for generic error handling since the error will bubble out of the instance_eval block scope. e.g. `module R; def self.with_error_handle(obj,&block); obj.instance_eval(&block) rescue "oops #{$!}"; end; end`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can build your own `with` using `instance_eval`.

```
def with(obj, &block)
  obj.instance_eval(&block)
end

with(" banana ") {
  puts strip
  puts reverse
}
```

Output:

```
banana
 ananab
```

Comment: Beautiful. I cannot think of a more simplistic example